# How to configure mail_report for every mailing?

Tags: civireport

I´m trying to configure the cron job mail_report. I need an email to be sent to the address example@myaddress.com every time a mailing is sent. The screen to configure it is in the following image[image: report sender screenshot]

What are the command parameters I need? I don´t see it clear in the "lear more" help..

Thanks a lot!

---

[image]

Hi davejenx, here´s another picture of what is happening now. I´ve put the id of the instance report (28 is the bouncing report). The log entry doesn´t seem to raise an error, but the screen gets blank on that url and does nothing :s

What I´m doing wrong?

Many thanks!

Comment: It seems like the question has changed over time - and it's very hard to understand what's currently being asked.  Please take a minute to read the introductory tour (http://civicrm.stackexchange.com/tour) so that we can better help you.  Please also consider asking for help on new issues in their own question, you'll get more/better responses.

Answer (score 3):

See [Managing Scheduled Jobs](http://wiki.civicrm.org/confluence/display/CRMDOC/Managing+Scheduled+Jobs#ManagingScheduledJobs-ScheduledJobs), for mail_report:

> Generates and sends a copy of the specified report instance to the
>   email addresses configured in that instance's Report Settings.

So you specify the email address in the settings for the report instance, not in the settings for the scheduled job.

Answer (score 0):

can you please tell me exactly where the settings of the report instance are? I can´t find them :s. I go to a sent mailing, click on report, and don´t find anything to configure..

Many thanks

Comment: Hi davejenx, sorry to insist :) Can you please guide me where to finde the report instance? thanks!!!!!!